# Removing Element from Dictionary's Values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary with list as its values, like this:
`{"a":[1,2,3,4,5],"b":[6,7,8,9,10]}`

How do I remove certain element from the dictionary values? For example, removing element `3` from key `a` will result: `{"a":[1,2,4,5],"b":[6,7,8,9,10]}`

I am using Python version 3.9.1.

Comment: I edited my answer, please check the Edit: part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a dictionary comprehension:

```
dct = {"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "b": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
print({k: [i for i in v if v != 3] for k, v in dct.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 4, 5], 'b': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

I iterate through the dictionary by key and value, I don't modify the keys, but I modify the values by iterating through the lists of each value, and only keep the list values if they aren't `3`.

**Edited:**

As the OP said in the comments, he wants to only remove the `3`s from the `a` key.

So try this:

```
dct = {"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "b": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
print({k: (v if k != 'a' else [i for i in v if i != 3]) for k, v in dct.items()})
```

Output:

```
{"a": [1, 2, 4, 5], "b": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: @AkhmadZaki I edited my answer, please check the **Edit:** part, and remember to accept and upvote if it works :-)

Comment: i tried it and it removed all of values of `b` key. @U11-Forward

Comment: @AkhmadZaki I edited my answer, it should work now

Comment: I think `v if k=='a'` should be `v if k!='a'`

Comment: @AkhmadZaki I am so sorry, please check the **Edit:** part again, it should definitely work now.

Comment: `print({k: (v if k == 'a' else [i for i in v if i != 3]) for k, v in dct.items()})` should be 
`print({k: (v if k != 'a' else [i for i in v if i != 3]) for k, v in dct.items()})`